# Django 1.6: Extending project template through app template

Tags: django, templates, django-1.6

Should be an easy answer but I don't seem to get it.

Django 1.4 used to have 1 folder `templates` with subfolders for each app. I would then extend the master template by writing:

```
{% extend "base.html" %} #extending the master
{% extend "app/base.html" %} #extending another template from an app
```

However, in Django 1.6 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) each app looks for it's own `templates` folder:

> ...we’ll put this one in the application’s template directory (polls/templates) rather than the project’s (templates)...

. Which is all good for modularity. But when I try to extend the base.html of the project (which all apps should extend) I get `TemplateDoesNotExist` error. I tried to correct the path in different ways but it didn't work:

```
base.html
templates/base.html
../templates/base.html
../../templates/base.html
../../../templates/base.html
projectname/templates/base.html
projectname/base.html
```

If you have an idea how to make this work, please let me know.

Cheers!
pp

Comment: Sounds to me like a problem with settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS. Can you share it and other related information (your project layout, etc)?

Comment: Where did you read that "in Django 1.6 each app looks for it's own templates folder." ?

Comment: @yuvi , Indeed, template dir was missing from the default settings file. Added it and it works now with `{% extends "base.html" %}` Do right the answer so I mark it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually means that it couldn't find the template you mentioned in the listed directories in `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`. And as you said in your comment, that turned out to be the problem